# Is there any command in Debian and Ubuntu similar to Red Hat sudo yum updateinfo list cves?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, security, cve

in Red Hat, I'm used to:

Check which cve currently affect the system and the severity:

```
sudo yum updateinfo list cves
```

Get more details about that CVE:

```
sudo yum updateinfo <CVE_NAME>
```

Install all packages that solve the security issue:

```
sudo yum update --advisory=<CVE_NAME>
```

Everything directly from the command line logged in the system with simple terminal commands.

Are there any similar commands/functionalities in Debian and Ubuntu without having to manually check https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/ and having a cves list related to my server current situation?

Thanks

Marco